# Can't play Bass F & G with Treble E

Tags: midi, digital-piano

I bought YamahaOrgue and started taking lessons online and as an intermediate step i downloaded (EOP, everyone piano), Now in the recent lesson the teacher played simple version of the (Irish Woman Washer), in this piece she pressed (Bass F and G together with Treble E), i grow to like midi more than the physical orgue/piano but when trying to press them together it did not work on my laptop!, so i tried couple of other programs but the problem persist, does anyone know how to resolve it ?!

I am sorry if i said wrong names, bcz i am newbie in the realm of playing music.

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to play using the *text keyboard* of your laptop?

Comment: Taking a wild guess from rather limited information, your issue is one of [keyboard rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_\(key\)) for which there is no fix except buy a keyboard with a higher rollover count… or indeed an actual musical keyboard.

Comment: @Tetsujin my thought indeed... I have an answer already, I'm just waiting for a confirmation, as I strongly hope that the OP is really not trying to learn music by using the computer keyboard, especially with alphabetic keys.

Comment: @musicamante yes, the laptop keyboard but it is not working

Comment: @Tetsujin but it work fine When playing Bass F & G with Treble G for instance

Comment: See musicamante's answer below - it can often depend on how closely-grouped the keys are; but you will never achieve any sort of musical proficiency trying to play a computer keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl;dr: **Just don't.**
Really, please.

You cannot learn to play music by using your computer keyboard. It's like trying to learn cooking using an excavator. Or to drive a car with your chin.

What you're experiencing is due to the [rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) limitation of common computer keyboards: they can handle only few keys pressed together. It's not just a matter of the number of pressed keys, but their position in the keyboard *matrix*: except from *modifier* keys (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>), there are only many (close) keys that can be kept pressed and correctly recognized as such at the same time, and the order of press events also matters.
Consumer keyboards usually can get up to 2-4 keys at maximum, depending on their position: the more they're close, the less you can press together.

There are some high-end "n-key rollover" keyboards, usually aimed for gamers, but their price is usually high (80-100$ at least), which makes it even more useless for this matter: playing with a computer keyboard (especially if using alphabetic notation) has really very limited benefits - if any. Besides the above problem, computer keyboards have layouts that don't follow "musical" requirements, so in the end trying to play with them is just uncomfortable, pointless and with great limitations.

I strongly suggest you to buy an actual keyboard: even a cheap and small one would be hundreds times better (for example, the M-Audio Keystation Mini).
You may not be used to that (and then believe that using your laptop's keyboard is better), but it's just a matter of habit, and in the long run (actually, not that long) you'll only see benefits.