# How to find songs to play on a virtual piano?

Tags: piano, practice

I've been trying to get started learning to play piano by playing songs on a virtual keyboard. The one I've found to be the best and have been using most recently is the one at https://recursivearts.com/virtual-piano/ . I'm looking for songs I can play on the top row with the "real" setting, so 11 notes. So far I've found three, "Row Your Boat", "Chopsticks", and "Twinkle Twinkle Little Star". All the other songs I've found can't be played on that row, is there a good place to find more? I'd like to find at least ten in total. Thanks.

Comment: Hi CharType. This site doesn't offer the kind of references you're looking for. But I do have one question about your post: what does "top row" refer to?

Comment: The "TAB" key through the "p" key.

Comment: Related: [Can't play Bass F & G with Treble E](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/113212), aka: don't try to learn to play piano by using your computer keyboard. You can find cheap USB midi keyboards (even less than 40-50$, you can find used ones on ebay at lower prices). You might believe that you cannot afford to buy a MIDI keyboard, even if cheap, but in fact "learning" to play your computer keyboard means just wasting your time.

Comment: You are ***NOT*** learning to play piano! You're learning to play tunes on a qwerty board. There's a heck of a difference, and it will not be much use to you very soon - in fact, i believe you've already discovered some shortcomings.

Comment: No problem with learning to play music on a computer keyboard, I bet music producers do that to program in notes and stuff. Be advised, though: your skill at the computer keyboard isn't going to translate onto the ivory.